# Time Complexity: Show the following problem belongs to FP

Tags: time-complexity

> Let $n > 0$ be an integer. Show that the rounded square root function
> $f(n) = ⌊\sqrt n⌋$ belongs to FP.

Suppose $n=x+y$, where $x$ is the largest perfect square which is at most $n$, and $y$ is the remaining integer. For a given $x$, checking whether $x$ is a perfect square is in time $O(\log n)$ (using binary search). Also, the remaining square root of $y$ part can be rounded off to 0 or 1 accordingly, which is in constant time $O(1)$. Is this rounding computation in constant time?

Comment: The $y$ part doesn't have to be 0 or 1. For example, $27 = 25 + 2$.

Comment: I don't understand which rounding computation you are referring to. Also, you haven't really presented an algorithm. You need to explain how to find $x$ efficiently.